# Look up fields not populating with flow

Tags: salesforce-flow

What am I doing wrong? My look up fields aren't populating and debug isn't showing any errors. The org I'm working in is npsp and program management module.

End goal: When user creates record on custom object called Application, a record should automatically be created on custom object ProgramEngagement. The 2 lookup fields on Application should auto-populate from custom objects ProgramEngagement and Program.

[image: Debug]
[image: Create records works but not updating lookup to link it]
[image: Lookup fields not populating]

Create records is working fine but when I assign fields with record ID's or text it isn't showing.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Just to clarify, is this a before or after save triggered flow?

Comment: It is after save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this is an After-Save, the issue is you're actually not updating the record with the new values you've assigned. This Flow occurs after the record has been committed to the database, so in addition to assigning the values to the record, you also need to include an Update Record node to commit the newly assigned values.

Comment: That fixed my issue.  Can't believe I missed something so simple!  THANK YOU SOO MUCH!!

Comment: No worries at all, I know that feeling!